# One-App SSH Logins using login shell?

Tags: linux, security, ssh, shell

I want to run an application on a Linux machine which will be accessed by most users using PuTTY. I want to start that app and, when it's done, I want it to end the SSH session. Is it secure/sufficient to use `chsh` to set their shell to the app? Do I need to do anything else (chroot jail)? This will be implemented on Ubuntu Lucid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tacking onto ErikA's suggestion.  You do not need to use keys to use the force command.

You can also specify something like this in your sshd_config.

```
Match User xxxx
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/nnnn

Match Group yyyy
    ForceCommand /usr/bin/nnnn
```

The one important bit is that you will need to check is to see if the application you force allows the user to actually start another shell or process.

Comment: Ooh, didn't know that. Good to know!

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider using public key auth and the "forced command" functionality therein. In each user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, do something like this:

```
command="/path/to/application" ssh-rsa <rest_of_users_public_key>
```

If you set this and turn off password auth (a very good practice anyway), it will ensure that the user will only ever be able to execute the specified application. If you are very confident that there are no means of users executing shell commands through this app, then a chroot jail may not be necessary, but that really needs to be left for you to determine.

Comment: I like this suggestion, but unfortunately it seems unlikely that my users will be willing/able (technically speaking) to install and manage public ssh keys without significant assistance &ndash; which, honestly, I don't have time to provide. I was planning to provide a low-security login to several different users, then have an app-specific login inside the app itself. Is this a terrible plan?

Comment: This comment is not correct. The authorized_keys options should be *before* the key content. See "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" in http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys for more clarification.

Comment: @bjeanes - good catch. I've updated my answer. Keep in mind that anyone can edit either questions or answers on Serverfault, so instead of downvoting, you could have just fixed my answer. Regardless, it's fixed now.

Comment: A good point. Upon re-reading my comment it seemed a bit harsh — that wasn't my intention. Thanks for fixing!

Comment: @bjeanes right on! There are definitely times when an answer is so horribly wrong that no one wants to bother fixing it. In cases of a slight syntax error or other small issue, I feel it's typically best to just fix it, as it was likely (as in this case) just an oversight.

Comment: Totally agree. I think I haven't been on SO for so long I forgot about that feature or it didn't exist when I was here last :)